# Create newcommand with parameters without #?

Tags: macros, footnotes

In understand the basic `\newcommand{name}[numberofargs]{functionbody}` but applied LaTeX strikes when I try to:

```
\newcommand{\starfootnote}[1]{
\fnsymbol{#1}\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\arabic}
```

and I get a `Missing number treated as zero` error. A more basic:

```
\newcommand{\starfootnote}[1]{\fnsymbol{#1}}
```

doesn't work either when I use `\starfootnote{my text.}`. While

```
\newcommand{\starfootnote}[1]{\footnote{#1}}
```

works. Note, I made the footnote thing work by renewing the command every time I need a symbol footnote, but I am looking for simple `\newcommand` solution here.

Comment: The command `\fnsymbol` wants a counter's name as argument. Can you be more specific on what's the intended behavior?

Comment: what is the intention of  `\arabic`  at the end of the definition? it requires a counter name argument.

Comment: Let me guess: you want a second set of footnotes but with symbols instead of numbers? If yes: should they use the same apparatus or seperate ones?

Answer (score 2):

The error is unrelated to your `\newcommand` usage, as you see if you uncomment the second line you get the same error if you use that code directly, not via a definition. You are passing the text of the note to `\fnsymbol`. I think you just want to locally redefine `\thefootnote` so

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\starfootnote}[1]{
\fnsymbol{#1}\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\arabic}

\newcommand\starfootnoteb[1]{%
{\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnote{#1}}}

and I get a Missing number treated as zero error. A more basic:


% doesn't work either when I use\starfootnote{my text.}. While

%doesn't work either when I use \fnsymbol{my text.}\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\arabic. While

doesn't work either when I use\starfootnoteb{my text.}. While

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes you're right locally redefining the footnote does the job. But I a) like to understand what I am doing and b) have a command `\starfootnote` to create footnotes with star symbols and an ordinary `\footnote` command that behaves like standard latex without the need of redefinition every time I use it. I think I do not get the `thefootnote` thing, is it a command? It would be very helpful if you could elaborate on that.